# Any idea why this css isn't working? I'm stuck

Tags: css, html

I may be missing something really simple here, but I am trying to style the background to my disqus comments to a white color (like the blog post content area) but for some reason the background of the site is still overriding my styling. I have no idea why. Here is my styles.css...Does any one see what's going on? (Here is a single post where you can see the background is white, although my css should be making it white, unless I'm doing something wrong. http://noahsdad.com/fox-4-interview-noah/ )

```
/*  
Theme Name: Standard-Child-Theme-1
Description: Standard is a meticulously designed and coded theme for professional blogging. It adapts to mobile devices and individual posts can be styled distinctly for words, images, quotes, links, videos, or statuses. It includes a light and dark style sheet and precision, zero-config SEO techniques are built-in. Visitors will love it. Search engines will love it. And you will love it.
Author: 8BIT
Template: Standard
*/

@import url("../Standard/style.css");

.dsq-full-comment { color: #F5F5F5 !important; }

#subscribe_dock input[type="submit"] { padding: 5px 2px; font-size:11px; }

/* Social Icons For Top Right Graphic */
#text-25    {position:relative;}
#social         {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/down-syndrome-blogs-noahs-dad.jpg) no-repeat; height:300px; width:300px; position:relative;}
.social_icon        {height:32px; width:32px; display:inline-block;}
.social_trans       {height:32px; width:32px;}
#social_dock        {position:absolute; top:70px; left:8px;}
#social_dock a *    {border:0;}
#subscribe_dock     {position:absolute; bottom:-5px; left:8px;}
#social #facebook   {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat;}
#social #twitter    {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -32px 0px;}
#social #youtube    {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -64px 0px;}
#social #rss        {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -96px 0px;}
#social #pintrest   {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -128px 0px;}
#social #googleplus {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -160px 0px;}

/* Needed In Order To Get Social Icons To Show Up Correctly */
div.social_icon img {background: none;}
```

Here is the code that was added to get it to work. Any ideas why I needed all of this code to get it to work? Thanks.

```
#disqus_thread {
    clear: both!important;
    background: white;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 20px;
```

Comment: You're *definitely* giving us the wrong part of your CSS.

Comment: @Purmou This is a child theme, so the only css in the child theme is what I just posted.

Comment: `#disqus_thread { background: white; }` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: You should review your question and reevaluate your problem. There's something missing from this problem to make it complete. Also, we can't rely solely on an external page. What you should do is try to replicate your problem on a smaller scale on a site like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the site. The `id` of the element that you want to target and change the background color of is `disqus_thread`. So find where that is in your CSS and add the appropriate styling there.

You can do this either in your `default.css` file or your `noahsdad.css` file. You could also add this line to any CSS file that you have access to:

```
#disqus_thread {
    background: #fff; // white
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is interesting is I had to add a lot of code to get this work, I'm sure why. I'll past the code above. Can you hel me understand why I needed all of that code in order to get it to work instead of just what you posted?

Comment: @RickSmith: Most of that CSS actually has nothing to do with the background...so I don't know what to tell you besides "you didn't need most of that code just to change the background color." :P

Comment: @pumou, ha,ha... what's strange is it wouldn't work unless that code is there....

Comment: @RickSmith: That's because you have `background:white;` there. Remember, I said *most* of it had nothing to do with it, not *all* of it. ;) By the way, are you the actual owner of that site?

Comment: Ha,ha..I understand that. But if I just put the background:white css in there it doesn't work. It only worked when I added all of that. Strange. And yelp. That's my son. :)

Answer (score -2):

background:invisible;
works in similar situations; but lots can be unseen when depending on a template.
Good luck.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to communicate, but there's no such thing as `background:invisible;`.

Comment: @Madmartigan Not sure what you mean? Where do you see that at?

Comment: @Madmartigan Oh..ha,ha..nevermind. I see what you meant. Ha,ha.. I was confused also. :)